# why I can't stop interval in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, react-functional-component

In my code I have some problems with intervals. I have situation like this

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (count >= 10) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      } else {
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>start</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

what am trying to do is to start an interval when user click a button and stop it when counter reaches 10, but it never stops and debugger says that inside `setInterval` count is always 0. Does anybody know what is the problem?  I also found that if I rewrite component to `class` component like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.state.count >= 10) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          count: prevState.count + 1,
        }));
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>start</button>
        <p>{this.state.count}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

it works perfectly.
I don't know what's happening and I spend almost day trying to figure out.
So does anybody know why `class` component works and why `functional` component doesn't?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every time your App functional component loads you are setting the state to "0". You need to use `useRef` so that when the App component updates, the previous `count` state is kept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're [seeing a stale `count` in the `setInterval` callback function since it captures the value at the time you're starting the timer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

You can use the "ref boxing" pattern to have a readable reference to the latest value of the state atom:

```
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(null);
  countRef.current = count;  // Update the boxed value on render

  function handleClick() {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (countRef.current >= 10) {  // Read the boxed value
        clearInterval(timer);
      } else {
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>start</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that you're currently not correctly cleaning up the timer on unmount, leading to React warning you about that when you'd unmount your app.  The same holds for your class component.